# Linking a div to the href inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make the whole `staff-container` linked to the first href inside of it. (The one in `staff-picture`). How do I write this with jQuery? I'm pretty confused with `attr()` and I know that I have to use it.

In the following HTML, the jQuery should make `staff-container` linked to google.com.

```
<div class="staff-container">
    <div class="staff">
        <div class="staff-picture">
            <a href="http://www.google.com/"><img src="img/people/teachers/ahmed.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <p><span class="bold">Mr. Ahmed</span><br />
        Ext. 13417<br />
        Room 417/323<br />
        <a href="mailto:email@wcskids.net">email@wcskids.net</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Thanks to the answers I used this jQuery:

```
$('.staff-container').click(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

If there is no link inside `staff-picture` I do NOT want it to link the email. If jQuery can't find the link in `staff-picture`, I want the click to do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
$('.staff-container').click(function(e) {

    if($(this).find('a').attr('href'))
        window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');       
    e.preventDafault();
});
```

like this..??If you want specifically first anchor tag then you can give like

```
window.location.href = $(this).find('a').eq(0).attr('href');
```

Comment: @Brett Merrifield is it useful for you..??

Comment: I was still getting linked to the email on the ones with no links in .staff-picture. But I changed if($(this).find('a').attr('href')) to if($(this).find('.staff-picture a').attr('href')) and it works perfect! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.staff-container').click(function() {
    var $first_link = $(this).find('a').first();
    window.location.href = $first_link.attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS version: should be a bit faster than jQuery

```
<script>
function link(loc){
    var href=loc.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
    console.log(this);
    console.log(href);
    loc.setAttribute("onclick","window.location.href='"+href+"'");
    loc.removeAttribute("onmouseover","");
}
</script>
<div class="staff-container" onmouseover="link(this)">
    <div class="staff">
        <div class="staff-picture">
            <a href="http://www.google.com/"><img src="img/people/teachers/ahmed.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <p><span class="bold">Mr. Ahmed</span><br />
        Ext. 13417<br />
        Room 417/323<br />
        <a href="mailto:email@wcskids.net">email@wcskids.net</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working tested